# Exit segue doesn't dismiss in iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uistoryboardsegue

*Does anybody faced the same issue that  exit segue doesn't dismiss the controller, which should be happen automatically on pop.*

I am stuck on this issue for a while, It is just showing this error lines "attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear".

I have just simply dragged a segue from my close button  to the little green "EXIT" icon at the bottom of my source view. 
added this line in view controller

```
- (IBAction)unwindToViewControllerNameHere:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    //nothing goes here
}
```

Comment: You need to explain more completely what you've done. I assume you're talking about an unwind segue? Are you doing a dismissal or pop in code also? How is the segue hooked up? From a button or cell, or from the controller itself? IF you're using any code to do this, show it.

Comment: Is that method (unwindToViewControllerNameHere:) called? If you haven't, you should implement prepareForSegue in the source view controller, and see if it's called.

Comment: No, it is not getting called